# JavaScript: location.href to open in new window/tab?

Tags: javascript, window.open, window.location

I have a JavaScript file from a third party developer. It has a has link which replaces the current page with the target. I want to have this page opened in a new tab.

This is what I have so far:

```
if (command == 'lightbox') {
 location.href="https://support.wwf.org.uk/earth_hour/index.php?type=individual";
}
```

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1254, accepted):

```
window.open(
  'https://support.wwf.org.uk/earth_hour/index.php?type=individual',
  '_blank' // <- This is what makes it open in a new window.
);
```

Comment: Worth to mention: Whether a new tab or window is created, is decided by the **browser** (setting).

Comment: @alex I edited this answer to make the important bit readable. If you don't approve of my formatting, may I suggest shortening the URL so that the second parameter fits within the unscrolling region?

Comment: Though late but useful, Someone asked if the `'_blank'` is default text or must be written that way or it does have any impact on the entire `window.open` (???)... Just for the records, the `_blank` can be `textString`. You could even write it as `my_newWindow` or whatever. Provided that: **The is no blank spaces in between the characters** also note that **this is NOT going to be the title*** of the new. window.

Comment: @ErickBest That's incorrect. `"_blank"` guarantees that the window/tab will be new. Anything else (besides the other special names) are giving that window the specific name, and subsequent links to that target will reuse the window. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7kGnM/).

Comment: Not really. Just commented out the 'if` statement in your fiddle. Both buttons work like VOODOO!. Try it and VOILA! `_random_string` works as well as `_blank`. In fact one of theAdvantages of this method is that the user has brand NewWindows for different purposes i.e: `my_SPORTS_Window`, my_NEWS_Window,`my_EMAIL_Window`...etc, & when S/he clicks on a Link that deals withSports, it'll goDirectly to `my_SPORTS_Window` and open there. How cool is that?, Please read thisDO NOT use target="_blank" by MDN. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open#Do_not_use_target.3D.22_blank.22

Comment: @ErickBest The `if` had nothing to do with it (it was used to ensure the clicks were from the `button` elements only). You're basically iterating what I mentioned in my comment.

Comment: @Alex.. I get your point bro. However, The `If` disables the use of other custom strings. Uncomment it and try something like `myNewTab`, or `my_NewTab` or `myNewTab_`... --The button goes dormant--. The reason why I mentioned you should remove the `if` is that the `if` obliges strings to start with an `_` (underscore) as in, it being the first char of the string. `//Removing it === BOOM!` any string will open a brand new Tab or Window depending on the browsers' specifics and the window can  be reused severally if necessary... If that's what you also mean, then we are on the same boat.

Comment: What is `type=individual`? Neither this nor the `_blank` part are necessary (any more). The `window.open` command opens a new browser window or tab by default.

Comment: This just triggers a pop up block notification in modern browsers, doesn't simulate a `_blank` anchor click at all.

Comment: popup prevented by browser.

Answer (score 51):

Pure js alternative to window.open

```
let a= document.createElement('a');
a.target= '_blank';
a.href= 'https://support.wwf.org.uk/';
a.click();
```

here is working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/Lamik/L4wax19t/) (stackoverflow snippets not allow to opening)

Comment: Triggers Chrome's built-in popup blocker in the latest Chrome here on Jan 4, 2022.

Comment: @Volomike In my chrome version is 96.0.4664.110 (Official Build) (arm64) (MacOs) - example works. What is you chrome version?

Comment: I am on Windows 10. Version 96.0.4664.110 (Official Build) (64-bit). When I click your example hyperlink, Chrome intercepts and blocks the popup and I get an alert on my address bar. https://www.screencast.com/t/b6wA1Vay

Comment: Perhaps you enabled popups from jsfiddle.net. That might be why you don't see the popup blocking.

Comment: This solution is better than `window.open` since it can work in safari

Answer (score 39):

If you want to use `location.href` to avoid popup problems, you can use an empty `<a>` ref and then use javascript to click it.

something like in HTML

```
<a id="anchorID" href="mynewurl" target="_blank"></a>
```

Then javascript click it as follows

```
document.getElementById("anchorID").click();
```

Comment: I was hopeful for this solution, however it does still seem to trigger the pop-up block (at least in Chrome). I have a feeling that the browser is aware that it's a javascript click and treats it differently.

Comment: Thank you Nathan. You're quite correct. You still get a pop up block message. I thought I'd cured it. In theory it should have worked. Andrew

Comment: `$("#anchorID")[0].click();`    to use this solution with jquery.

Comment: Lol theBell, It's not jQuery if you are accessing directly DOM Element `[0]`

Comment: This is the best solution. Works in safari too.

Comment: This solves my problem, thanks.

Comment: This is the perfect solution. Works in all browsers without blocking.

Comment: Safari blocks this solution.

Answer (score 13):

You can open it in a new window with `window.open('https://support.wwf.org.uk/earth_hour/index.php?type=individual');`. If you want to open it in new tab open the current page in two tabs and then alllow the script to run so that both current page and the new page will be obtained.

Comment: Triggers Chrome built-in popup blocker.

Answer (score 11):

usage of `location.href` will replace current url with new url i.e [link](https://support.wwf.org.uk/earth_hour/index.php?type=individual) in the same webpage.

To open a new tab you can use as below:

```
if (command == 'lightbox') {
 window.open("https://support.wwf.org.uk/earth_hour/index.php?type=individual", '_blank');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
    $(document).on('click','span.external-link',function(){
        var t               = $(this), 
            URL             = t.attr('data-href');        
        $('<a href="'+ URL +'" target="_blank">External Link</a>')[0].click();

    });
```

Working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/Lgga124n/).

Comment: Popup prevented by browser.

Comment: It means that you either have an adblock or something else that blocks it. The default behaviour should be working under normal conditions

Answer (score 0):

You can also open a new tab calling to an action method with parameter like this:

```
   var reportDate = $("#inputDateId").val();
   var url = '@Url.Action("PrintIndex", "Callers", new {dateRequested = "findme"})';
   window.open(window.location.href = url.replace('findme', reportDate), '_blank');
```

Comment: Are the first and second line required? Won't it work without the `reportDate` and `url` variables?

Comment: You can take out the parameter (reportDate), but the url var is important because it contains the call to the action method.