# Javascript mailto function loading issue

Tags: javascript

I'm using JavaScript `mailto` function and when clicking on the button the mail loads in the same tab. How can I load the mail in a new tab?

Here's my code:

```
<input type="button" value="Apply" name="apply" onclick="mailJob('Sample');">
```

```
function mailJob(code)
{
    window.location="mailto:example@gmail.com?subject="+code;
}
```

Comment: read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141910/javascript-location-href-to-open-in-new-window-tab

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `window.open` function.

```
window.open('mailto:example@gmail.com?subject='+code, '_blank')
```

Read more [here](http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jwinopen.htm).

Answer (score 0):

window.location will redirect the current page to the indicated url. In order to open a new window or tab, you need to do window.open, as is shown in answer that Yan linked to.