# Check if user is accessing from a browser

Tags: php, browser

Recently, a friend of mine posted their email address using the `mailto` tag and has received a lot of spam bots because of this.

I'm just wondering whether or not it is possible to detect whether a person is using a "proper" browser to access the webpage, and, if they are, display the email address, if they are not, then do not display their email address?

I know you can get what someones email address is using `HTTP_USER_AGENT` but I don't really want to have to compile an array of the capable browsers and just wondered whether or not there is a pre-defined function in PHP.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. I'm not asking for specific code, references will do.

Comment: You can't. Browser is a program so does a bot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, parse the array or leave it

E:
Regarding your spam bots, assembly the emailadresse for the mailto with javascript, works fine for me and i never got spammed

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could I do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11595160/javascript-mailto-function-loading-issue?

Comment: could be even simpler var a = 'firstpart_of_mail'; var b = 'second_part_of_mail'; document.getElementById('mail-link').innertext = 'mailto:'+a+'@'+b; (without warranty ;))

Answer (score 1):

While you could filter browsers by UserAgent from listings such as [user-agents.org](http://www.user-agents.org) or use the built in detection through the [get-browser method](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php), you're still likely to get your address picked up by spiders if it's displayed in the raw html, due to UserAgent Spoofing. You are better off using javascript to display a mailto link, using `window.open("mailto:example@example.com")` with whatever other parameters you want to have included, and triggering using `<a onclick="jsfunction" href="javascript:void(0);">`.

EDIT: Or dynamically forming the link using a script on page load.

Comment: Note that there are already some bots that are smart enough to run javascripts. Its like warfare. You come up with a good idea to block, but after a while, they come up with a way around it. :(

Comment: True, true. A dynamically generated link is probably the best bet then. As it affords the simplicity of a mailto, without the ease of running a script. Though all of the above approaches fail if the bot uses a simulated browser environment like PhantomJS.