# jquery how to make a clickable div open in a new window

Tags: jquery, target

I want to make a DIV with no content clickable for that I use this jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#whole").click(function () {
    window.location = $(this).attr("href");
    });
});

</script>
```

It works fine, but the link always opens in the same window. How do I need to change the code, to make the div open in a new window?

Comment: `window.open('http://www.yoururl.com');`

Comment: Exact duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141910/javascript-location-href-to-open-in-new-window-tab

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("#whole").click(function () {
   window.open($(this).attr("href"), '_blank');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need [**window.open**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

```
window.open($(this).attr("href"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#whole").click(function () {
    window.open("href"); // window.open('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13452398/jquery-how-to-make-a-clickable-div-open-in-a-new-window');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do by following method

1)

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$("#divId").click(function () {
window.open("openThisPage.html"); //Change 'openThisPage.html' to your target page
});
});
```