# Auto Click on MouseOver in new window

Tags: javascript, html

This code is working fine..

```
<a href="http://google.com/" onmouseover="window.location=this.href">Text</a>
```

But I need to open the link in a new tab

Comment: wait. onmouseover to navigate to new page? seems a strange user experience (UX). and `onmouseover` is not supported in touch devices.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: location.href to open in new window/tab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141910/javascript-location-href-to-open-in-new-window-tab)

Comment: do some googling dude 
there are lots of answers for this already

Comment: @ShivanRaptor, I mean new window/tab not tablets or touch devices.....window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank');.....open in new window but I need in new tab not new window!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `window.location`, you can use:

```
window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank');
```

to open in new window.

Comment: window.open('google.com';, '_blank');.....open in new window but I need in new tab not new window!

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4907854/188331 . No script can control the new content be open in new tab / new window. Depends on browser settings !

Answer (score 0):

You can use it. But New Window

```
<a href="#" onmouseover="javascript:window.open('http://google.com')">Text</a>
```

OR use javascript. This **New TAB**

```
<a href="#" onmouseover="myFunction()">Text</a>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var Open = window.open("http://www.kangsigit.com", "_blank");
}
</script>
```