# JavaScript confirm dialog in new window/tab

Tags: javascript, url, alert, target, confirm

I have a confirm dialog appearing on a form, which redirects the user to another page when clicked on ok.

However, is it possible to have that page open in a new window (e.g. target="_blank")

The code that I'm using is:

```
var answer=confirm("Do u want to continue?") {
if (answer==false) {
document.form.field1.focus();
return false;
}
window.location.href = "/some/url"
}
```

Comment: Check for `window.open` but It will be new window not tab.

Comment: posible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141910/javascript-location-href-to-open-in-new-window-tab

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript open in a new window, not tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726761/javascript-open-in-a-new-window-not-tab)

Answer (score 0):

So `window.location` refers to the location of your current window, so changing it of course takes you away from the window you're on. To open a new window, you want `window.open` - see [Open a URL in a new tab (and not a new window) using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript)

However, I'd suggest instead, using a link that you intercept the default behavior for if the user answers false, and otherwise fallback to the default behavior.

ie:

```
<a href="/some/url" id="foo">bar</a>

$('#foo').click(function(e){
  var answer=confirm("Do u want to continue?") {
     if (answer==false) {
       document.form.field1.focus();
       e.preventDefault();
     }
  }
});
```

Although I'd have to double check if that actually works, I haven't worked with confirm much at all, so you might have to call the e.preventDefault() outside of that block.

Answer (score -2):

```
window.open(
  '/some/url',
  '_blank'
);
```