# Href vs select box

Tags: javascript, html, href

I use my web space in a non-Professional way though I own a web page with some links and use  Javascript to automatically load the url.

http://samuel.dumont.pagesperso-orange.fr/

I wanted JS to open in `_self` or `_blank`.
It's ok with regular `href` links for both target even with the "block popup" feature of the browser  but on select box (with onChange event) _blank is only granted with this feature off.
Does `href` encode url differently from a select box value ?
Is there a wizard tips to locally overcome this feature ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141910/javascript-location-href-to-open-in-new-window-tab

Comment: this will help u: http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/navmenu.html

Answer (score 2):

Fixed your function, tested on my localhost, link opens in new tab.

```
<a href="Javascript:GoTowww('http://goggle.com/')">Google</a>


function GoTowww(url) {     
  window.open(url,'_blank');
}
```

I find a solution for your checkboxes

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/nBdkC/)

```
<select onchange="window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'_blank')">
  <option value="">Choose</option>
  <option value="http://www.yahoo.com/">Yahoo</option>
  <option value="http://www.google.com/">Google</option>
  <option value="http://www.stackoverflow.com/">Stackoverflow</option>
</select>
```

more resource [Here](http://lab.artlung.com/dropdown/)

Comment: I didn't know of your solution sooner.I should visit my Stackoverflow more often.
Yet, Expert ideas are always good to know.
Thank you