# D3js: how to open new tab after doubleclick on element?

Tags: d3.js

On my dataviz, both the input topojson and the svg polygons contains an attributes `name:"..."` and `data-name="..."`, respectively. In my D3js code I currently have :

```
function click(a){console.log(a.properties.name);}
```

which successfully print out the name's value.

In addition to this, **how could I add a **double click** to open a new tab with the url `"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/"+a.properties.name` ?**

---

Edit: Doubleclick is likely to be `on("dblclick", function(){...})`, but you may think to other ways. I also prefer to build the url from the properties.name rather than store it into the SVG, which will make it uselessly heavier.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: On the track, thanks !

Comment: Thanks, answer documented (if it wasn't already !)

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141910/javascript-location-href-to-open-in-new-window-tab. I voted to close (but as a duplicate of a different question, because I found that one first, but the question I linked to in this comment is a better match).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, opening a **PAGE on doubleclick** :

```
 function dblclick(a){
    window.location.assign("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/"+a.properties.name, '_blank');
 }
```

you then simply add `.on("dblclick", dblclick);` in your D3 element generation :

```
 svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "L0" )
  .selectAll(".countries")
    .data(topojson.feature(world, world.objects.admin_0).features) 
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("data-name-en", function(d) { return d.properties.name; })
    .style("fill", "#E0E0E0")
    .attr("d", path)
    .on("dblclick", dblclick);
```

and it will work (if no other element is upon your target).

Secondly, **opening a NEW TAB** [is known as depending on the browser and user's preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/). The `'_blank'` upper ask for a new tab/windows, but this depend on the browser default and custom preferences.

Comment: Actually this never works for me. However the window.open(url,'_blank');
window.open(url); (see this answer too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript?lq=1)

Answer (score 7):

I found the window.open method works (in the oncick below).

```
vis.selectAll("text")
      .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("svg:text")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return d.children ? "parent" : "child"; })
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .style("opacity", function(d) { return d.r > 20 ? 1 : 0; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .on("click",function(d){
          window.open(d.url, '_blank')});

      d3.select(window).on("click", function() { zoom(root); });
});
```