# How to take off the text showing a link in the left bottom corner of the screen?

Tags: javascript, css, html, browser

I'm editing my post, which is a duplicate of this issue here : [How to hide link information at the bottom left/right of the browser on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30410748/how-to-hide-link-information-at-the-bottom-left-right-of-the-browser-on-hover)

I have this code from that post :

```js
var aTags = document.querySelectorAll('span[data-href]');

for(var i = 0; i < aTags.length; i++){
    var aTag = aTags[i];
    aTag.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        var ele = e.target;
        window.location.replace(ele.getAttribute('data-href'));
    });    
}
```

```css
span[data-href]{
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<span data-href="http://www.google.com">test</span>
```

I have tried to change that example which is on a span, to an anchor, and the results are only visual, when i click on my anchor it doesn't start any exernal link, i've tried also an JS alert.

Am i missing something ?

Comment: are you using the hover attribute or you setting a listener with javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide link information at the bottom left/right of the browser on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30410748/how-to-hide-link-information-at-the-bottom-left-right-of-the-browser-on-hover)

Comment: It's an event listner, i'm hovering an anchor who is gonna start a JS method. "add()"

Comment: @OscarO. i'll check, thanks.

Comment: @OscarO. the code provided in the other post didn't completely solve my problem