# How do I adjust this code so that it will open the redirect in a new tab/window?

Tags: javascript, redirect

Apologies, I am very bad at coding and writing HTML, hence I was wondering if someone could show me how to change this code below so that the redirect opens in a new tab/window, and does not replace the current tab/window. Thanks in advance.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
parent.location.replace('http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/live/uk-england-norfolk-35590969?ns_mchannel=social&ns_source=facebook&ns_campaign=bbc_live&ns_linkname=56defd473e000055b12aceec&Watch%3A+Starlings+take+flight+over+Norwich&&ns_fee=0#post_56defd473e000055b12aceec');
</script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141910/javascript-location-href-to-open-in-new-window-tab

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick

```
window.open('http://your-url.com', '_blank')
```