# Ajax response data should display in a seperate php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, search

I have jQuery AJAX function that returns HTML that display result in some few page  page where i mention the class

**What I want**

I Want that result should display in separate file i.e(`testsearch.php`) present on the test site: [kargal.in](http://kargal.in/)

My code :

```js
$("#searchsubmit").on('click', function(event){
    var maincat = $('.country').val(),
        subcat1 = $('.city').val(),
        subcat2 = $('.third').val(),
        subcat3 = $('.fourth').val(),
        searchkey = $('.search_key').val();

    event.preventDefault();

    //if(maincat == "" || subcat1 == "" || subcat2 == "" || subcat3 == ""){
    if(maincat == ""){
        alert("Please select the main category.");
        return false;
    }

    $(".searchCnt").html('<div class="srchloader"><img src="<?php echo     site_url();?>/search_loading_img.gif"><br /> Loading...</div>');

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "<?php echo site_url();?>/ajax_city.php",
        data: {
            action: 'search',
            maincat: maincat,
            subcat1: subcat1,
            subcat2: subcat2,
            subcat3: subcat3,
            searchkey: searchkey,
        },
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        success: function(responsedata) {   
            $(".post-block-out").remove();

            if(responsedata != ""){                 
                $(".searchCnt").html(responsedata); 
            }
            else {
                $(".searchCnt").html('<div class="srchnoRec">No ads found.   </div>');
            }
        } 
    });
});
```

Comment: So what's the problem? How does the code fail?

Comment: Its Not Fail.. the Search Result should display in new separate file. kindly check in http://kargal.in

Comment: What do you mean by "separate file"? A new tab? You are requesting content from the server, then putting it in a div. What exactly do you want to do instead? "display in a separate file" doesn't make _any_ sense.

Comment: now its display result in current page (url), I want that should display Search result in New tab with url of http://kargal.in/testsearch.php

Comment: If you want that, you don't need AJAX. Just send the form the regular way using `target="_blank"` in `<form>` and `<input type="submit">`.

Comment: Its not working... still Load in same page. For info. the result will display only where i  mention <div class="searchCnt"></div> in php file

Comment: Did you actually *disable* the AJAX code you posted above? If I look at kargal.in, I can still see it.

Comment: maybe `window.open` works for you, an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5141926/521880)

Comment: @ramabarca No, don't. Why make this complicated, given how simple it is?

Comment: when i disable the code the sub category  drop down fail to function..

Comment: You need to disable _only_ the click handler for "#searchsubmit", not your entire JS code.

Comment: You're almost there. Put "testsearch.php" as your `action`.

Comment: Whoops! Page Not Found. :-(

Comment: You need the proper path. Where in your `public_html` folder is `testsearch.php` located? The `action` attribute works exactly like the `href` in a link. You need to state the proper relative path.

Comment: yes.. I think it work thank you @ChrisG..

Comment: No.. Its Return blank page ..  :-(