# Is there any way to redirect to a basic html page from an angular2 component?

Tags: html, angular, angular2-routing

I have a search.component.ts, where I am fetching data according to search criteria.
Now I want to generate a report which is a basic html page and not search.component.html, based on the data I have in my search component. 
I want the html page to be opened on a different tab. 
Is there any suitable solution?

Answer (score 0):

Create a button in your template:

```
<button type="button" (click)="redirect">Redirect</button>
```

Create a function in your component:

```
redirect(){
    window.open(
        'https://support.wwf.org.uk/earth_hour/index.php?type=individual',
        '_blank' // <- This is what makes it open in a new window.
    );
}
```

Ps. A simple google search found the window.open() function that accepts a second param to open a new window. see link [JavaScript: location.href to open in new window/tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141910/javascript-location-href-to-open-in-new-window-tab)