# Vuejs redirect to url when clicked on a button

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a button on which when I click I want it to redirect to a url that is begin passed in it.

Here is my code.

```
<template>
<button type="button" v-on:click="gotosite(modalDetails.final.product_url)">Buy</button>
</template>

<script>
 .
 ..
 ...
 .....
 methods : {
        gotosite(producturl){
        this.window.location.href = producturl
            }

</script>
<style></style>
```

When I click on the button it doesnot redirect me to a url.

I am thinking of making the  tag look like button and use it redirect it but how to do it via button.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That maybe is because window isn't an object of `this`. Try using just `window.location` and it should work just fine.

Comment: it worked.
But how to make it open in a different tab?
right now it is opening in the same tab.

Comment: @handsomer223 [that can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141910/javascript-location-href-to-open-in-new-window-tab)

Comment: @handsomer223 don't forget to pick the working answer ^^, Cheers!