# AngularJS: Load two url one by one in a newly opened tab on ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It's very easy to open two URL one by one by using interval but in the same tab.

e.g.

```
<div ng-click="openTwoUrl()">Click Me</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$scope.openTwoUrl=function(){
    $window.location.href='www.linkone.com';

    //Below will wait for the above link to be fully loaded.
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        if(document.readyState === 'complete') {
            $window.location.href='linktwo.com';
            clearInterval(interval);
        }    
    }, 100);
}
```

But my requirement is that I want to open these URL to be open one by one in a new tab.

So to open a new tab I use `$window.open('www.firstlink.com')` and immediately a new tab is opened and now I want that in that newly opened tab my second URL i.e `www.secondlink.com` to be loaded.

Searched a lot but didn't found anything. Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

**NOTE:**

[JavaScript: location.href to open in new window/tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141910/javascript-location-href-to-open-in-new-window-tab)

This question doesn't give me the solution to my problem

Comment: Have you tried      var win = window.open(url, '_blank'); win.focus();

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: location.href to open in new window/tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141910/javascript-location-href-to-open-in-new-window-tab)

Comment: @mcarton how it can be a duplicate? My question is asking to open two urls one by one in a new tab. But your posted question is telling how to simply open a singe url in a new tab

Comment: @Davesoft if you can explain more about it, that would be great

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible in pure javascript unless you are writing a chrome extension of some sort.

You would need to pass javascript from one tab to the other. That would require cross site-scripting which is a security vulnerability! Websites would never allow that.