# How can i open this javascript in new page or tab?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

Happy New Year!
I have this bookmarklet but it opens in the same page. How can i force it to open in new tab?

```
javascript: var lingq_base_url = %27https://www.lingq.com%27;(function()%7B(function()%7Bvar b=function()%7Bwindow.lingq_bookmarklet%3Flingq_bookmarklet():window.setTimeout(b,500)%7D,c=document.getElementsByTagName("head")%5B0%5D,a=document.createElement("script");a.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");a.setAttribute("src",lingq_base_url+"/bookmarklet/bookmarklet.js");c.appendChild(a);b()%7D)()%7D)()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome.  Your code appears to be  copy-paste from something that has injected character encoding.  Can you please copy / paste from your original script code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: location.href to open in new window/tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141910/javascript-location-href-to-open-in-new-window-tab)

Answer (score 1):

Use window.open funtion for the new tab. See the example below.

```
window.open(url, '_blank');
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all of you!
I think i found my answer i have added  `window.open(window.location.href, '_blank');`
this one at the end of my bookmarklet. It opens the same page and bookmarklet also works. Looks like doing the reverse:)

Answer (score 0):

Try it.
I am not sure about your URL.

HTML

```
<p onclick ="OpenNewTab()">Click Me.</p>
```

Script

```
<script>
function OpenNewTab(){

window.open('%27https://www.lingq.com%27;(function()%7B(function()%7Bvar b=function()%7Bwindow.lingq_bookmarklet%3Flingq_bookmarklet():window.setTimeout(b,500)%7D,c=document.getElementsByTagName("head")%5B0%5D,a=document.createElement("script");a.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");a.setAttribute("src",lingq_base_url+"/bookmarklet/bookmarklet.js");c.appendChild(a);b()%7D)()%7D)()','_blank');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The bookmarklet upload the selected text the website (lingq.com)

I have added javascript in front of the your code. Does it must be like that?

```
    javascript: function OpenNewTab(){

window.open('%27https://www.lingq.com%27;(function()%7B(function()%7Bvar b=function()%7Bwindow.lingq_bookmarklet%3Flingq_bookmarklet():window.setTimeout(b,500)%7D,c=document.getElementsByTagName("head")%5B0%5D,a=document.createElement("script");a.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");a.setAttribute("src",lingq_base_url+"/bookmarklet/bookmarklet.js");c.appendChild(a);b()%7D)()%7D)()','_blank');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.open to go to a url.

```
window.open("www.url.com");
```

You can also pass few arguments to determine how the url be open.

- _blank - URL is loaded into a new window. This is default
- _parent - URL is loaded into the parent frame
- _self - URL replaces the current page
- _top - URL replaces any framesets that may be loaded

You can pass there arguments like this.

```
window.open("www.url.com","_blank");
window.open("www.url.com","_parent ");
window.open("www.url.com","_self ");
window.open("www.url.com","_top");
```

There are few other parameters that you can use. (specs, replace)

Use this link to read more: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp