# React, how to open onclick function on a new tab?

Tags: reactjs, redirect, routes, onclick

In react how do you redirect or open something in new tab? I have a button and on click I want to open it in new tab. For now it opens in current tab. here is the button code

```js
<Button
                                  variant="contained"
                                  fullWidth={true}
                                  color="primary"
                                  disabled={loder === data._id ? true : false}
                                  onClick={() => viewRecording(data)}
                                >
```

Here is that function

```js
const viewRecording = (sessionData) => {
    setLoder(sessionData._id);
    const val = {
      meetingId: sessionData.meetingNo,
    };
    const onSuccess = (data) => {
      setLoder(null);
      console.log(data.recording_files);
      window.location.replace(data.recording_files[0].play_url);
    };
    const onError = () => {
      setLoder(null);
      openSnackbar("Recording not found for this session !!");
    };
    dispatch(ZoomMeetingRecording(val, onSuccess, onError));
  };
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript: location.href to open in new window/tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141910/javascript-location-href-to-open-in-new-window-tab)

Comment: @Quentin how can implement it in my current case?

Answer (score 2):

Just use

```
window.open(data.recording_files[0].play_url, '_blank');
```

Instead of

```
window.location.replace(data.recording_files[0].play_url);
```