# How to open a link in a new tab using react?

Tags: reactjs

I have that function :

```
const test =  () => {
    var url = "https://www.google.fr";
    window.location.href = url;
    }
```

But I would like to open Google in a new tab. How can I do to do that ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript: location.href to open in new window/tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141910/javascript-location-href-to-open-in-new-window-tab)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one:

> window.open(URL, '_blank');