# Open new tab without rewrite previous open tab but open new one

Tags: javascript, html, tabs

I google many times for looking for a way to open new tab on link click. If I click on link this javascript snippet open new tab and it's perfect, but if I click again new tab take focus and replaced with new content. I don't want this.

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.viewTextAndAnnotations', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var fullUrl = "https://www.example.com";
      window.open(fullUrl,'_newtab');
});
```

I would like that in second click user open second tab.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript: location.href to open in new window/tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141910/javascript-location-href-to-open-in-new-window-tab)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this.

```
 function openWindow( url )
    {
      window.open(url, '_blank');
      window.focus();
    }

<a href="http://www.example.com/" onclick="javascript:openWindow(this.href);return false;">Click Me</a>
```

Comment: Yes, to use _blank is the solution. Thank you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).